# strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given CORE/Cake/I18n/I18n.php, line 140

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-2.2

I'm using Cakephp 2.2.2 on this project and I'm getting this error:

```
Warning (2): strpos() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given [CORE/Cake/I18n/I18n.php, line 140]
```

I'm not sure what is causing this.  I'm not using I18n that I know of and I'm not sure what I did do get this install of Cake to do this.

In addition I'm also getting this error, however, I believed this one is caused by the first.

```
Warning (2): Illegal offset type in isset or empty [CORE/Cake/I18n/I18n.php, line 196]
```

Comment: click on the `Warning` link and you should be able to see the line in your app that raises this message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably passing an integer, array, or some other type to __().  Have a look at the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/global-constants-and-functions.html) for proper usage.

Comment: Thanks! I had never looked up what `__()` did.  Your answer caused me to look at the stack trace and sure enough there it was.  I an error in my view template which caused it to show up on most pages. Thanks again!